# Find rows where column value for entire group is 'P'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table "Camera", I need to find the camera's who has only used Camera_mode 'P' and no other mode.

Table structure

```
Cam_serial_no     Camera_mode

abc123             P
abc123             B
abc123             V
pqr111             P
xyz101             P
xyz101             V
xyz101             B
```

I could get desired output using below query, But I was wondering if there is any easy way

```
select * 
from (select Cam_serial_no, collect_set(camera_mode) as val 
      from camera 
      group by Cam_serial_no
) a 
where size(val)=1 and val[0] = 'P';
```

desired output is

```
pqr111             P
```

Comment: You are looking for the `HAVING` clause. See juergen d's answer on that. There are many ways to check the values; e.g. `having min(camera_mode) = 'P' and max(camera_mode) = 'P'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by the `Cam_serial_no` and take only those having no other mode than `P`

```
select Cam_serial_no
from camera
group by Cam_serial_no
having sum(Camera_mode <> 'P') = 0
```

Comment: Hi Juergen,

I am getting below error when i run your query in Hive;

FAILED: UDFArgumentTypeException Only numeric or string type arguments are accepted but boolean is passed.

Comment: Because MySQL != Hive. The syntax is different. This should work for almost all DB engines: `having sum(case when Camera_mode <> 'P' then 1 else 0 end) = 0`